# Swift: Contact delegates not working?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im creating a simple game that involves collision detection and using a tutorial as a guide. Ive copied the code almost verbatim (changing constant names, etc) and have set it so that when two objects collide, one should disappear and the game over screen should pop up(have yet to write code for that, but you get it).

When I run the project, I have absolutely no errors, yet my sprite just moves over the obstacle without doing what it should. Was wondering if anyone could help me figure this out.

**Edit:** My code--

```
}
func obstaclePhysics() {
    let obstacle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fruit_strawberry_100")
    obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: obstacle.size.width / 4)
    obstacle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    obstacle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    obstacle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    obstacle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.obstacle.rawValue
    obstacle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue
    obstacle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0




}
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask |             contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
switch(contactMask) {
case BodyType.player.rawValue | BodyType.obstacle.rawValue:
    let secondNode = contact.bodyB.node
    secondNode?.removeFromParent()
    let firstNode = contact.bodyA.node
    firstNode?.removeFromParent()
default:
    return
}
```

}

Comment: Some code would really help to solve your issue.

Comment: Please post the code for your bitmask values, as well as the creation of the sprites in question.